# Blueprints plugin for Cytoscape, Gephi etc

Tags: gremlin, cytoscape.js, gephi, blueprint

I'm building UI to visualize and edit graph which is present in a gremlin store.
Which framework is better Cytoscape.js vs Gephi.js Vs other?
Do these frameworks have Blueprints plugin available? I want to avoid writing  module to convert the gremlin output to the framework compatible format.

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from the Cytoscape development team...

Well, there are a number of ways you can use Cytoscape with TinkerPop, but I would think that the best way would be to use the REST interface to Cytoscape and inject your graph directly into it.  You could save your graph as a Neo4j database and use the Neo4j app to pull it into Cytoscape or save your graph as a GraphML or some other common graph format and read it in that way.  Neither Cytoscape or Gephi are UI frameworks, though -- both are standalone applications that are designed to import, visualize, analyze and manipulate very large graphs.

A good place to start is on the Cytoscape Automation topic in the Cytoscape manual: http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Programmatic_Access_to_Cytoscape_Features_Scripting.html

Comment: I'm referring to Cytoscape.js and Gephi.js which are UI frameworks which helps me bring this graph browsing functionality into my tool. I think you are referring to the Cytoscape tool itself which I don't want to use.

Comment: Got it. Updated tags to clarify. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No matter which library you use for graphs on the web, you're going to have to convert your model to the JSON format used by the library (e.g. the [Cytoscape JSON](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json) format if you use Cytoscape desktop or Cytoscape.js).